# ObjectAnimator: animation caption from constants

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator

I've create an animation by calling:

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(null, "translationX", 0f, 200f);
```

Can I get "translationX" from any animation constants?

Comment: no, it is `View#TRANSLATION_X` where it is defined

Comment: @pskink Oh, thanks a lot!

Comment: Question is closed